# WordPress - wp_update_post() doesn't update post with a custom type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new post type called 'produkty'. It works well, I can add new posts, so it's working properly. What I am trying to create is a front-end editor for single.php. To make it update a post I am using `wp_update_post()`.

However it's not really updating the content at all.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['singleedit'])) {
    $args = array('ID' => $post->ID, 'post_content' => $_POST['singleedit'], 'post_type' => 'produkty');
    wp_update_post($args);
}
```

Both issets launch correctly and the values are also good. I have no idea why nothing gets updated. Could anybody help me with it?

Comment: where are you setting $post?

Comment: the code looks fine, are you sure you have $post->ID set?

Comment: Thanks @David, you helped me realize something. I accidentally inserted this snippet below another definition of $post, so the array was overwritten. Attention failure on my side. Please post it as an answer and I will select it as correct.

Comment: I can upvote you @VidyaLB too if you post an answer, you were also correct about $post->ID not being set due to my misplacement of the snippet. David got it first though.

Comment: thanks anyway but its not really a useful answer for others! If you want though have a look at some of my other answers and if you find them useful you can vote on them!